# Unix time in millisecond to d-m-Y

Tags: php-5.2, unix-timestamp

I'm pulling a unix time in milliseconds from an xml document but can't convert it to a readable date (d-m-Y) in php 5.2.17.

I've used http://www.epochconverter.com/ which converts it correctly
from **1328723926776** to **2/9/2012 13:37:49**

I've tried the following:

```
$timestamp = $xml['LastBackupDate'];
echo '<br />Method 1: '.date("d-m-Y", $timestamp);
echo '<br />Method 2: '.date("d-m-Y", strtotime($timestamp));
echo '<br />Method 3: '.date("d-m-Y", strtotime($timestamp*1000));
echo '<br />Method 4: '.date("d-m-Y", strtotime($timestamp/1000));
echo '<br />Method 5: '.date("d-m-Y", $timestamp/1000);
echo '<br />Method 6: '.date("d-m-Y", (int)$timestamp);
echo '<br />Method 7: '.date("d-m-Y", intval($timestamp));
echo '<br />Method 8: '.date("d-m-Y", intval($timestamp)/1000);
echo '<br />Method 9: '.date("d-m-Y", intval($timestamp/1000));
```

which brings back:

```
Method 1: 
Method 2: 01-01-1970
Method 3: 01-01-1970
Method 4: 01-01-1970
Method 5: 25-01-1970
Method 6: 19-01-2038
Method 7: 19-01-2038
Method 8: 25-01-1970
Method 9: 25-01-1970
```

Any ideas how to convert this?
Thanks!

---

**Edit, Best result from using:**

```
echo date("d-m-Y", substr($xml['LastBackupDate'],0,-3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried *dividing* by `1000`, instead of multiplying?  Epoch time is usually in seconds ...

---

OK, so now I actually need to learn PHP ...

`date` takes a format and a time.
`strtotime` takes a human-readable date/time string and returns a time.  Your value is epoch time in milliseconds, not a human-readable string, so isn't a valid argument to `strtotime`.

Try *Method 4* without the `strtotime`, it shouldn't be needed.

---

Right, that didn't work, because `$timestamp` is a string (I'd assumed it was already an integer).

You say that dropping the last 3 characters of the string gets you most of the way, that is the same as converting to an integer and then dividing by 1,000. Your methods 6 & 7 convert to int but don't divide - you need both!

According to [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), `date` requires an *integer* timestamp *in seconds*. The value you have is a string, so you should convert it to an integer.  It is also in milliseconds, so you have to divide by 1,000 to get the right units.

Note that epoch time is counted as seconds since the first of January, 1970. So, any time you see `01-01-1970`, the second argument evaluated to zero.

```
date("d-m-Y", $timestamp);                 <-- string, not int: treated as zero
date("d-m-Y", strtotime($timestamp));      <-- not a formatted time, gives zero
date("d-m-Y", strtotime($timestamp*1000)); <-- ditto
date("d-m-Y", strtotime($timestamp/1000)); <-- ditto
date("d-m-Y", $timestamp/1000);            <-- clearly nonzero, but no idea what!
date("d-m-Y", (int)$timestamp);            <-- correct type but in milliseconds
date("d-m-Y", intval($timestamp));         <-- correct type but in milliseconds
```

If you pass an integer containing a number of seconds rather than milliseconds, it should be correct.

Like so:

```
date("d-m-Y", intval($timestamp)/1000);
```

Comment: just done that and updated the initial question... but it didn't help.

Comment: Edited.  Your _Method 1_ didn't call `strtotime`, and I think that was correct (only the units were off).

Comment: I've made that change and added method 5 - doesn't seem to be working but the output is different... any other ideas?

Comment: Interesting, when I run `ctime(1328723926)` it gives me `Wed Feb  8 12:58:46 2012`, which looks plausible. Is your `$timestamp` a string, and do you need to convert it to an integer explicitly?

Comment: ok think I've figured it out to some degree....

I had to remove the last 3 digits from the unix time using:

$timestamp = substr($xml['LastBackupDate'],0,-3);

and it gave me 08-02-2012 instead of the exact correct date of 09-02-2012. I think this is something to do with it not being able to read the full unix time. Anyways its close enough for me. Thank you!

Comment: division by 1,000 should have the same effect, _if it were an integer_ :-)